# I tested my app on Windows Subsystem for Android (windows 11) and it gave me a bunch of "update color buffer" log

Tags: java, android

I have connected WSA to my windows and able to test my app through it. But the screen keeps flickering with many black parts. I checked the logcat and the log kept printing this line whenenver the screen flicker:

```
D/gralloc_emulation: Updating color buffer (source=0x7d4655a1a3e0, size=11184), (dest=0x7d446d23f010, size=1449984)
```

WSA is kinda new but i hope there will be a good solution for this.